# Ejs inside an html tag

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

```
  <input type="checkbox" 
         <% if(email.status === 1) { %> checked <% } else { %> <% } %> >
```

I would like to show a checked or unchecked check box depending on a query result using EJS. But of course html thinks that the first %> is the closing tag. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks

[image]

Comment: What you have there should work. How are you rendering this page?

Comment: it does not work. I am using ejs. I have put a scree-shoot so you can visualize what happens

Comment: I am not able to see the screenshot but I did test your code and it loaded fine. I will post the code below

Comment: I see the screenshot now. Is the issue the IDE is complaining or you can't display the page? If the IDE is complaining try finding a EJS plugin for whatever IDE you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following displayes the page. My guess is you aren't passing the email.status variable in which is causing a server error. Or you are trying to use the browser to render the ejs page, which will not work you need to use a view engine.

**checkbox.ejs**

```
<input type="checkbox" <% if(email.status === 1) { %> checked <% } else { %> <% } %> >
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': 'true'})); 
// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render("pages/checkbox", {email: {status: 1}});
});

app.listen(8000);
console.log('Server is running on port 8000');
console.log('http://localhost:8000/');
```

> node app.js